# Invite your facebook,twitter,gmail friends control for ios app?

Tags: xcode, ios, facebook, gmail

I want to find an opensource or a free control for cocoa couch, what is like WeCity invite friends page? [image: invite frineds page]

Is there any ready to use component out in the market? Or I must create it? I don't want all in one component, if something missing from the list above, I don't care. But I want to find a "stater" component, what I can upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [ShareKit](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit)

Comment: Thanks! I need time to get inside of that, but seems to be great. I try to integrate some openid based stuff too.